# Como criar efeito (shadow, pulse) animado para Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Como criar o efeito em azul (shadow? pulse?) como no gif abaixo em um UIButton ou UIImage no Xamarin.iOS?

[image: Exemplo do efeito animado desejado]

Comment: É pra ele ficar piscando indefinidamente ou surgir e parar com o shadow azul nele?

Comment: O efeito/animação deve funcionar em um loop infinito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar essa função abaixo, da seguinte forma:

```c#
Shine(true, meuBotao);

// muito código

Shine(false, meuBotao);
```

A função tem o seguinte código:

```c#
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using MonoTouch.CoreAnimation;

void Shine(bool active, UIView view) {
    if (view == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("view");

    if (active) {
        view.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
        view.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.0f;
        view.Layer.ShadowRadius = 6.0f;
        view.Layer.ShadowOffset = SizeF.Empty;
        view.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;

        var glow = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("shadowOpacity");
        glow.AutoReverses = true;
        glow.Duration = 0.5;
        glow.To = NSNumber.FromDouble (0.9);
        glow.RepeatCount = int.MaxValue;

        view.Layer.AddAnimation (glow, "glow");

    } else {
        view.Layer.RemoveAnimation ("glow");

        if (view.Layer.ShadowColor == UIColor.Blue.CGColor) {
            view.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
            view.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.0f;
            view.Layer.ShadowRadius = 0.0f;
            view.Layer.ShadowOffset = SizeF.Empty;
            view.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c#
var shadowView = new UIView(textView.Frame);
shadowView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowRadius = 6.0f;
shadowView.Layer.ShadowOffset = new System.Drawing.SizeF(0f, 3f);
shadowView.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
shadowView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;

Add(shadowView);
Add(textView);
```

O que você quer fazer se aproxima disso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]